# Substitute text on active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to substitute text in active cell. From "sum Total" to "sum".

My code is:

```
Sub Macro2_substitute()    
  cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "Total", "")   
End Sub
```

It doesn't work. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## Substitute vs Replace

Your corrected line of code:

```
Sub SubstituteActiveCell()
```

> ```
>   ActiveCell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveCell, " Total", "")
> ```

```
End Sub
```

where you have forgotten the space before the Total. To avoid this, it is often better to substitute or replace what was given.

VBA has a similar function called Replace:

```
Sub ReplaceActiveCell()
```

> ```
>   ActiveCell.Replace "sum Total", "sum"
> ```

```
End Sub
```

which should be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With ActiveCell
    .Value2 = Worksheetfunction.Substitute(.Value2, "Total", "")
End With
```

If you want to get the value of the active cell or currently selected cell, use `ActiveCell`.
I used `With` clause to explicitly call it, but it can be written like this too.

```
ActiveCell.Value2 = Worksheetfunction.Substitute(ActiveCell.Value2, "Total", "")
```

This works as well, but implicit.

```
ActiveCell = Worksheetfunction.Substitute(ActiveCell, "Total", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit
Sub SubstituteTotal()

    Dim rng As Range, cll As Range

    Set rng = Selection

    For Each cll In rng
        cll.Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cll.Value, "Sum Total", "Sum")
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.